# How can you add a template for a custom confirmation page URL?

Tags: 8, webforms

I want to show custom message on confirmation page (on custom URL). 
I created a custom URL in *.routing.yml file and added a method in controller class that returns an array :

```
return [
  '#theme' => 'mycustom_confirmation',
  '#test_var' => 'Test Value',
];
```

Next, in *.module file,

1. I added hook_theme function to return below array:

```
    'mycustom_confirmation' => [     
          'variables' => ['mycustom_var' => NULL, 'webform' => NULL, 'source_entity' => NULL, 'webform_submission' => NULL],
        ]
```

2. I added template_preprocess_mycustom_confirmation function to add my customized variables.

Then I created a template file: mycustom-confirmation.html.twig file where I consume the customized variables to show custom message.

After all that, when I landed to confirmation URL (that I set in to admin/structure/webform/manage/webinar_training_request_1/settings/confirmation page) after webform submission , I dont see any message. I dont understand what I missed in module.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a nice starting point:

/erlendsays.module

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function erlendsays_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 'store_doublecheck_form_result');
}

function store_doublecheck_form_result(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  Drupal::request()->getSession()->set("webform_result", $form_state->getValues());
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function erlendsays_theme() {
  return [
    'doublecheck_form_result' => [
      'variables' => [
        'form_result' => NULL,
      ],
      'template' => 'doublecheck_form_result',
    ],
  ];
}
```

/erlendsays.routing.yml

```
erlendsays.doublecheck_form_result:
  path: '/doublecheckformresults'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\erlendsays\Controller\DoublecheckFormResultController::index'
    _title: 'DoubleCheck Form results'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

/erlendsays/templates/doublecheck_form_result.html.twig

```
<p>TODO: print the form result.</p>
```

/erlendsays/src/Controller/DoublecheckFormResultController.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\erlendsays\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class DoublecheckFormResultController extends ControllerBase {

  public function index() {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'doublecheck_form_result',
      '#form_result' => \Drupal::request()->getSession()->get("webform_result"),
    ];
  }

}
```

Comment: oh, here I have used a webform and in confirmation page settings, I chose a custom URL for showing confirmation message. Here I am expecting to use webform_submission values too in confirmation page template.  Do I  need to add any preprocess confirmation handler ?

Comment: What would be the content of the message on the confirmation page? What is de flow that the user follows and how does the message add value?

Comment: well, we send wenform submission to third party component and confirmation URL that redirected with extra parameters in querystring. So on confirmation page I need to show some webform field's data (like personalizing confirmation message) along with query parameters values